# How to extract a value from a JSON response with Java and Rest-Assured

Tags: java, api-testing, rest-assured, jsonpath

I'm getting the response below. I need to assert the value of "Type". How can I get the value? I'm using Java and rest-assured

The response:

```
"Product1": {
    "Productive1": {
        "applause": {
            "home-Only": {
                "Component-write": {
                    "Default": [
                        {
                            "Type": "123456",
                            "Name": "product-1",
                            "profile": "employee",

                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "office -Only": {
                "Fee": {
                    "Default": [
                        {
                            "Type": "123456",
                            "Name": "Produc-2",
                            "profile": "boss",

                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying with this code:

```
List<String> ObjectList1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(Generic.response.getBody().asString());

            Set<String> a = jsonObject.keySet();

            for (Object objj : a) {
                    String element = (String) objj;
                    ObjectList1.add(element);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ObjectList1.size()-1; i++) {
                    JSONArray obj1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(ObjectList1.get(i)).names();
                    System.out.println(obj1);
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Provide more details to the problem that you are facing just copy pasting the code doesn't help. Also go through the link [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center].(https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: What results do you get from running your code?

Comment: JSONObject["Product1"] not found i'm getting this error

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing is called a JSON object. Unless you're in JavaScript (that can natively parse JSON data) you can use a *jsonpath* language that is very similar to xpath (serves for similar purpose). Using jsonpath query you can access any JSON part (including what you're looking for). Here are few refs for different tools/languages (not neccessery related to JSONpath):

- [JSONpath implementation for Java](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/releases)
- [Parsing JSON in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)
- [JSONpath in REST-Assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath)
- [JSONPath in SOAPUI](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/assertions/reference/property/json-match.html)
- [Parsing JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620173/8343843)
- [Parsing JSON in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21210869/8343843)